# Draw Horizontal Line with Pine Script and Set Text to always stick to right

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

```
//@version=5
indicator("Horizontal Line with Text", overlay=true)

var label label1 = na
value = 42800

hline(value, title="HR Line", color=color.blue, linestyle = hline.style_solid, linewidth = 2)

if(barstate.islast)
    label1:= label.new(bar_index, value, text="Horizontal Line from script: Always Floating", xloc=xloc.bar_index, style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.white, textalign=text.align_left, size = size.large)
```

This code shows the horizontal line, but doesn't position the text to **stick to right**, in-fact the position changes when I resize/realign the chart.
But when I add Horizontal line manually and add text in Trading View, the text sticks to right.

[image]

Is it possible to position text stick to right in Pine Script ?

Comment: I don't see a label on my chart. https://www.tradingview.com/x/VEfxpKF2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chart.right_visible_bar_time` for that. It won't be as smooth as the manually added one but it's still something.

In order to use that, you need to set `xloc=xloc.bar_time`.

```
label1 := label.new(chart.right_visible_bar_time, value, text="Horizontal Line from script: Always Floating", xloc=xloc.bar_time, style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.white, textalign=text.align_left, size = size.large)
```